# Zeroes of the floor (greatest integer function)

Tags: complex-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions, wolfram-alpha

I was just browsing Wolfram Alpha and looking at interesting graphs of functions when I noticed that it gave complex numbers for the numerical roots of $\lfloor x\rfloor$. Does anybody know why?

Comment: They are roots, so I expect giving those two in particular is some quirk of their root-finding algorithm.

Comment: Just a guess, but it's probably giving the complex roots of the Fourier series expansion of this function extended to the complex numbers.

Comment: I looked it up and I found that there should be no Fourier series expansions for greatest integer function.

Comment: To make your questions a bit more complete, you could add a link (to the page where you saw these complex roots). I have added some tags; of course, if you don't find them suitable for your question, feel free to edit it again.